# Magento 2 Custom Module New Controller Issue

Tags: magento2, controllers, custom, admin-controller

I have created listing & it's working fine with database.

Now i'm trying to create "Add Form" for that.

> {folder
>   path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\NewAction.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Custom_Module::save');
    }

    /**
     * Forward to edit
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
     */
    public function execute() {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward $resultForward */
        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
        return $resultForward->forward('edit');
    }
}
```

It's giving below error.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument
>   1 passed to
>   Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\NewAction::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, none given,
>   called in {folder
>   path}\magento2\var\generation\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\NewAction\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in {folder
>   path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\NewAction.php
>   on line 20

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130465/fatal-error-on-controller-accessing-session

Comment: It Solves. Why there is need to remove folder from var/generation. How to ignore it?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html